# Vaadin remove pages after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

As documented on https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security, in a Java Spring Vaadin application, annotations can be used to define if pages should be shown after login based on Roles like this:

```
@Route(value = "admin", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Admin View")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN") // <- Should match one of the user's roles (case-sensitive)
public class AdminView extends VerticalLayout {
    // ...
}
```

Or pages can always be shown with:

```
@Route(value = "home", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Homepage")
@AnonymousAllowed // or @PermitAll 
public class HomePageView extends VerticalLayout {
    // ...
}
```

But what I'm missing in the documentation, is how a page can be hidden after a user has logged in. **Is some kind of "negative" annotation available?** E.g.

```
@Route(value = "register", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Register as a new user")
@RolesNotAllowed({"ADMIN", "USER"}) // <- This annotation doesn't exist (yet?)
public class RegisterView extends VerticalLayout {
    // View only needed for users who didn't login yet
}
```

---- Update 20220103

One solution is to remove the page from the menu by checking the authenticated user:

```
Optional<User> maybeUser = authenticatedUser.get();
if (accessChecker.hasAccess(RegisterView.class)
    && !maybeUser.isPresent()) {
    nav.addItem(new AppNavItem("Register", RegisterView.class, "la la-user"));
}
```

But still, the page can be accessed directly via the URL. As suggested by @gidravlic, I tried to remove the page from the route configuration, but it's still accessible. So this is not a "full" solution. This doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
if (maybeUser.isPresent()) {
    RouteConfiguration configuration = RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope();
    configuration.removeRoute(RegisterView.class);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this issue is helpful: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-connect/issues/370

Comment: As it seems the functionality you are asking for does not exist in form of annotations: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security/#annotating-the-view-classes

Comment: Maybe you can hide the page through removing route for session [https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/dynamic/#removing-routes](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/dynamic/#removing-routes)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I found a "partial" solution by removing the option from the menu. See the update in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BeforeEnterObserver` and the `BeforeEnterEvent` to forward the user to another view when they're trying to access one that they're not supposed to:

```java
@Route(value = "register", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Register as a new user")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class RegisterView extends VerticalLayout
        implements BeforeEnterObserver {
    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (hasLoggedIn()) {
            event.forwardTo(SomeOtherView.class);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasLoggedIn() {
        Optional<User> maybeUser = authenticatedUser.get();
        return maybeUser.isPresent();
    }
}
```

You can update the menu e.g. with the `MainView`'s `AfterNavigationObserver` which works similarly to the `BeforeEnterObserver` except it gets triggered after all navigation activities are completed.

Comment: You _can_ add and remove routes dynamically through the RouteConfiguration, but you still probably want to deal with users accidentally or intentionally going to the `/register` URL so you'll probably end up doing some sort of redirect or forward regardless.